# Reading data in a variable

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java and am currently stuck with my assignment at school.
I am trying to read the data from a file that has both strings and Integers.

```
------ *-----------------*----------
Sample data in the file
John mathew 0 2 3 4 
Brian Barrow 4 3 2 
------ *-----------------*----------
```

I was given the below piece of code I have all my results in a variable "atBatResults"
Could some one tell me how do i red the data in the variable "atBatResults"
how do i tell the computer "If atBatResult is an integer then do this else if it is a string then print it"

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
        String lastName = input.next();
        String firstName = input.next();
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int atBatResult = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(lastName);
            System.out.println(firstName);
            System.out.println(atBatResult);
```

When i print the "atBatResult" i get a list of all the numbers in my input file.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have all my results in a variable `atBatResults`"*?

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you want to achieve?

Comment: also mention what datatypes of these variables are.. (since you are mentioning that "I have all my results in a variable atBatResults".

Answer (score 0):

`atBatResult` is declared as `int`, so it must be an integer. You don't need to check it.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but do you want something like that,

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
        String lastName = input.next();
        String firstName = input.next();

        System.out.println(lastName);
        System.out.println(firstName);
        int atBatResult;
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            atBatResult= input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(atBatResult);
        }
    }
```

you can do anything with the integer values in the second while loop. You don't need to check Because they are already 'int' you just need to implement what you want to do with them